# Is this way of instantiating a dependency injected class correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I was implementing dependency injection for the first time, and encountered with the "can't use the constructor" issue. I made a get around doing the following:

This is the constructor for the class that needs *IHttpClientFactory* and *IMemoryCache* dependencies. It's a class to manage and cache OAuth tokens.

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

public AuthManager(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

And this is where I instantiate *AuthManager*, at Home Controller:

```
// I used dependency injection here, too,  and passed it through constructor.
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    _logger = logger;
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    //Code skipped for reading
    //Passed the needed instances through parameter here
    var authManager = new AuthManager(_httpClientFactory, _memoryCache);
    ...
}
```

It seems so wrong using dependency like this. ¿How can I better build this?

Comment: No, you should inject `AuthManager` into the constructor, or `IAuthManager` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. I would create AuthManager as Interface (IAuthManager) which is implemented in AuthManager class.
You can than, in startup.cs (.NET 5.0) add a scoped service:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthManager, AuthManager>();
```

HomeController.cs would look like this:

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IAuthManager authManager)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _logger = logger;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _authManager = authManager;
    }
```

Comment: Worth noting that you probably don't need `httpClientFactory` and `memoryCache` anymore if they were only used to instantiate the auth manager class.

Comment: @DavidG I agree.